# Docker Nginx Configuration - Keeps redirecting to HTTPS in browsers

Tags: docker, nginx, https, docker-compose

I am trying to create a local development environment using docker-compose. It is using the following services:

- php-fpm
- nginx
- varnish
- redis
- mariadb
- elasticsearch
- phpmyadmin

I have everything set-up up correctly as far as I am aware: containers are running fine, logs show no errors. I am pointing a domain in my hosts file something like:

```
127.0.0.1       my.domain.dev
```

If I run `curl -I my.domain.dev` I get the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 20 Mar 2018 09:14:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Set-Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=www-data; expires=Tue, 20-Mar-2018 10:14:07 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
Set-Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=www-data; expires=Tue, 20-Mar-2018 10:14:07 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
Location: /setup/
Set-Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=www-data; expires=Tue, 20-Mar-2018 10:14:24 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
Set-Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=www-data; expires=Tue, 20-Mar-2018 10:14:24 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
Set-Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=www-data; expires=Tue, 20-Mar-2018 10:14:24 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
Set-Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=www-data; expires=Tue, 20-Mar-2018 10:14:24 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
Set-Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=www-data; expires=Tue, 20-Mar-2018 10:14:24 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
Set-Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=www-data; expires=Tue, 20-Mar-2018 10:14:24 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
Set-Cookie: XDEBUG_SESSION=www-data; expires=Tue, 20-Mar-2018 10:14:24 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

But in any browser (tried chrome and firefox so far) it keeps redirecting me to https:

[image: Keeps directing to HTTPS]

I have tried the following:

- Flushed the cache & cookies "Since the beginning of time",
- Excluded my domain from HSTS
- Tried to add a self signed certificate to my docker nginx build
- Gone searching through nginx settings to see if there are any redirects happening (no there are not).

**Update**

Also tried:

- Private / Incognito window
- Checked DB for any form of incorrect URL references

If anyone can find something I am missing I would be very grateful. Many thanks.

Here is a link to the Nginx conf: https://pastebin.com/y5ieHBLh - let me know if you need any more (such as the include files).

FYI this is configuration specific for a Magento 2 project.

**Workaround**

I found by entering the results of the following command:
`hostname -i`
typed directly into the browsers then garner a result. It's almost like my hosts file isn't being picked up. Here is an example of what I am doing:

```
127.0.1.1   my.domain.com
```

Comment: just open it in private window and will see every thing work :D

Comment: Sorry, yes have tried that!

Comment: Show us: nginx configuration, browser network stack (you should see the redirect), access logs

Comment: Thanks, have added above as edit. Regarding access logs: When I ```curl -I``` I see entries in the access logs but none from the browser. I think this is because varnish is hit first. I am in the process of looking through the varnish logs, I think they are a bit more hidden!